# Center vertical the text with image in unorederd list

Tags: html, css

I have some `<ul>` and `<li>`  with text images. The problem us the text shows on the bottom of the image. Is there a way to make in the center?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 3
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 4
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what im trying to achieve:

[image]

**Note:** The images are different every `<li>` and I dont need to use `<ul>` necessarily. Open for `<div>`s etc

Comment: Do you want add text over the image?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use display flex method...

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul li img{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAMDAwMDAwQEBAQFBQUFBQcHBgYHBwsICQgJCAsRCwwLCwwLEQ8SDw4PEg8bFRMTFRsfGhkaHyYiIiYwLTA+PlQBAwMDAwMDBAQEBAUFBQUFBwcGBgcHCwgJCAkICxELDAsLDAsRDxIPDg8SDxsVExMVGx8aGRofJiIiJjAtMD4+VP/CABEIAEYARgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAZAAEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABwYEAwn/2gAIAQEAAAAA+gAAlGKCsbRG8GFk3iN4MLJvMHGwUatYONg3lkwcbBvLJ4cSUYo3lkHHznR2f//EABwBAAICAgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcIAAQCBgMFCf/aAAgBAhAAAADzNIM6EfENlYO1rZQiTU1TKZEIOrKhOSxjV//EABsBAAICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcIAAYCAwQF/9oACAEDEAAAAPYGUsZNF6ownteqAwlzcsODAZ29z5p5cu7/xAAtEAABAgIJBAIBBQAAAAAAAAACAQQDEQAFBxU1VXSTshASINEGUTETFCMwMv/aAAgBAQABPwD+r53WVYM63gw27txBBWgqohEIUn3kk5JS/K6zJ5vn7pfldZk83z90vyusyeb5+6X5XWZPN8/dL8rrMnm+funwR26eVRHNxHixjR2SIUQ1NZdgrKa9bQ8agaMOZeVnmCx9YfAetoeNQNGHMvKzzBY+sPgPS0PBYGsDgXnZ49c/vY7Pv/g/ROL2ST/cxGc/z+OloeCwNYHAvOzzGo+jPmPS0PBYGsDgXnZ5jUfRnzHo4atXgIDiDCjAizQYgISIv3JaXHUuWs9gPVLjqXLWewHqnztq1Z1vBBvAhQQVoKqIAgJPuJJyTws8xqPoz5j4uKuq94aG4aQIxokkI4Yksvqa0uOpctZ7AeqXHUuWs9gPVLjqXLWewHqjerqvZmpt2kCCapJSCGIrL6mnT//EACoRAAEDAgQEBgMAAAAAAAAAAAIBAwQFBgAHEBIRIjZ0FRcxVZKxUlST/9oACAECAQE/ALcoL1x1MYLTwNEoEW4kVU5ceUFS9yj/AALHlBUvco/wLFx5fTLcphTnZjLoo4IbRFUXm0yv6sa7d3XNDpRzuGfvTK/pRvuHdb5abdtSp7wEtrO4eKceCovqmlpZgw7co4QXYbzpI6ZbhJETmxbmYMO46mMFqG80Stke4iRU5dL26Uqvbr96tPPMHvacNsvyFVRceJ1L9yR/UsHPnugoHKfIV9RVwlRdP//EACwRAAECBAQFAgcAAAAAAAAAAAIBAwQFBhAABxIiETZ0k7EXVRMVIVRxkdH/2gAIAQMBAT8Aqmo2aWlJTB5g3hFwA0AqIu7849b5V7VFdwcet8q9qiu4OKWzNgapmwy9mAfZImzPWZCqbbZvcmu9Ux5vlFzm10r3i2bvObvSs+L5evOs1lKPhmQa39JaVVOIqn1RbVplnHVTPDmLMcwyJNNhoMSVduKpyzjqWlJTB6OYeEXADQAki7rUDznJuqTxd5hmIDQ82Dg8U2mKEn6XHymVfYwvaH+YCWy5kxNuEhwIV4oQtiipb//Z">    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAMDAwMDAwQEBAQFBQUFBQcHBgYHBwsICQgJCAsRCwwLCwwLEQ8SDw4PEg8bFRMTFRsfGhkaHyYiIiYwLTA+PlQBAwMDAwMDBAQEBAUFBQUFBwcGBgcHCwgJCAkICxELDAsLDAsRDxIPDg8SDxsVExMVGx8aGRofJiIiJjAtMD4+VP/CABEIAEYARgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAZAAEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABwYEAwn/2gAIAQEAAAAA+gAAlGKCsbRG8GFk3iN4MLJvMHGwUatYONg3lkwcbBvLJ4cSUYo3lkHHznR2f//EABwBAAICAgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcIAAQCBgMFCf/aAAgBAhAAAADzNIM6EfENlYO1rZQiTU1TKZEIOrKhOSxjV//EABsBAAICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcIAAYCAwQF/9oACAEDEAAAAPYGUsZNF6ownteqAwlzcsODAZ29z5p5cu7/xAAtEAABAgIJBAIBBQAAAAAAAAACAQQDEQAFBxU1VXSTshASINEGUTETFCMwMv/aAAgBAQABPwD+r53WVYM63gw27txBBWgqohEIUn3kk5JS/K6zJ5vn7pfldZk83z90vyusyeb5+6X5XWZPN8/dL8rrMnm+funwR26eVRHNxHixjR2SIUQ1NZdgrKa9bQ8agaMOZeVnmCx9YfAetoeNQNGHMvKzzBY+sPgPS0PBYGsDgXnZ49c/vY7Pv/g/ROL2ST/cxGc/z+OloeCwNYHAvOzzGo+jPmPS0PBYGsDgXnZ5jUfRnzHo4atXgIDiDCjAizQYgISIv3JaXHUuWs9gPVLjqXLWewHqnztq1Z1vBBvAhQQVoKqIAgJPuJJyTws8xqPoz5j4uKuq94aG4aQIxokkI4Yksvqa0uOpctZ7AeqXHUuWs9gPVLjqXLWewHqjerqvZmpt2kCCapJSCGIrL6mnT//EACoRAAEDAgQEBgMAAAAAAAAAAAIBAwQFBgAHEBIRIjZ0FRcxVZKxUlST/9oACAECAQE/ALcoL1x1MYLTwNEoEW4kVU5ceUFS9yj/AALHlBUvco/wLFx5fTLcphTnZjLoo4IbRFUXm0yv6sa7d3XNDpRzuGfvTK/pRvuHdb5abdtSp7wEtrO4eKceCovqmlpZgw7co4QXYbzpI6ZbhJETmxbmYMO46mMFqG80Stke4iRU5dL26Uqvbr96tPPMHvacNsvyFVRceJ1L9yR/UsHPnugoHKfIV9RVwlRdP//EACwRAAECBAQFAgcAAAAAAAAAAAIBAwQFBhAABxIiETZ0k7EXVRMVIVRxkdH/2gAIAQMBAT8Aqmo2aWlJTB5g3hFwA0AqIu7849b5V7VFdwcet8q9qiu4OKWzNgapmwy9mAfZImzPWZCqbbZvcmu9Ux5vlFzm10r3i2bvObvSs+L5evOs1lKPhmQa39JaVVOIqn1RbVplnHVTPDmLMcwyJNNhoMSVduKpyzjqWlJTB6OYeEXADQAki7rUDznJuqTxd5hmIDQ82Dg8U2mKEn6XHymVfYwvaH+YCWy5kxNuEhwIV4oQtiipb//Z">    Item 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 3
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 4
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
ul img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 3
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 4
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, that does not help with line-breaking text. For that to work, you'd have to use a different approach with the image floating left:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul img { vertical-align: middle; }

.multiline-text img { float: left; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 3
  </li>
  <li>
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">    Item 4
  </li>
  <li class="multiline-text">
    <img width="70px" height="70px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAMDAwMDAwQEBAQFBQUFBQcHBgYHBwsICQgJCAsRCwwLCwwLEQ8SDw4PEg8bFRMTFRsfGhkaHyYiIiYwLTA+PlQBAwMDAwMDBAQEBAUFBQUFBwcGBgcHCwgJCAkICxELDAsLDAsRDxIPDg8SDxsVExMVGx8aGRofJiIiJjAtMD4+VP/CABEIAEYARgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAZAAEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABwYEAwn/2gAIAQEAAAAA+gAAlGKCsbRG8GFk3iN4MLJvMHGwUatYONg3lkwcbBvLJ4cSUYo3lkHHznR2f//EABwBAAICAgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcIAAQCBgMFCf/aAAgBAhAAAADzNIM6EfENlYO1rZQiTU1TKZEIOrKhOSxjV//EABsBAAICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcIAAYCAwQF/9oACAEDEAAAAPYGUsZNF6ownteqAwlzcsODAZ29z5p5cu7/xAAtEAABAgIJBAIBBQAAAAAAAAACAQQDEQAFBxU1VXSTshASINEGUTETFCMwMv/aAAgBAQABPwD+r53WVYM63gw27txBBWgqohEIUn3kk5JS/K6zJ5vn7pfldZk83z90vyusyeb5+6X5XWZPN8/dL8rrMnm+funwR26eVRHNxHixjR2SIUQ1NZdgrKa9bQ8agaMOZeVnmCx9YfAetoeNQNGHMvKzzBY+sPgPS0PBYGsDgXnZ49c/vY7Pv/g/ROL2ST/cxGc/z+OloeCwNYHAvOzzGo+jPmPS0PBYGsDgXnZ5jUfRnzHo4atXgIDiDCjAizQYgISIv3JaXHUuWs9gPVLjqXLWewHqnztq1Z1vBBvAhQQVoKqIAgJPuJJyTws8xqPoz5j4uKuq94aG4aQIxokkI4Yksvqa0uOpctZ7AeqXHUuWs9gPVLjqXLWewHqjerqvZmpt2kCCapJSCGIrL6mnT//EACoRAAEDAgQEBgMAAAAAAAAAAAIBAwQFBgAHEBIRIjZ0FRcxVZKxUlST/9oACAECAQE/ALcoL1x1MYLTwNEoEW4kVU5ceUFS9yj/AALHlBUvco/wLFx5fTLcphTnZjLoo4IbRFUXm0yv6sa7d3XNDpRzuGfvTK/pRvuHdb5abdtSp7wEtrO4eKceCovqmlpZgw7co4QXYbzpI6ZbhJETmxbmYMO46mMFqG80Stke4iRU5dL26Uqvbr96tPPMHvacNsvyFVRceJ1L9yR/UsHPnugoHKfIV9RVwlRdP//EACwRAAECBAQFAgcAAAAAAAAAAAIBAwQFBhAABxIiETZ0k7EXVRMVIVRxkdH/2gAIAQMBAT8Aqmo2aWlJTB5g3hFwA0AqIu7849b5V7VFdwcet8q9qiu4OKWzNgapmwy9mAfZImzPWZCqbbZvcmu9Ux5vlFzm10r3i2bvObvSs+L5evOs1lKPhmQa39JaVVOIqn1RbVplnHVTPDmLMcwyJNNhoMSVduKpyzjqWlJTB6OYeEXADQAki7rUDznJuqTxd5hmIDQ82Dg8U2mKEn6XHymVfYwvaH+YCWy5kxNuEhwIV4oQtiipb//Z">    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
  </li>
</ul>
```